# SAP.net Connector using reflection C#

Tags: c#, reflection

We are using SAP.net connector in C# windows service application, as per license documentation on SAP page, the libraries are not redistributable(sapnco.dll, sapnco_utils.dll), the customer needs to have its own licensed copy of the library, and we are using DirectoryCatalog(MefFunctions.GetPlugInDir()) to load all assemblies from plugin folder so over without physical copy of dll the windows service application does not work and it throws an error that the sap dlls are missing as we have added dll's as part of references, could you please help to overcome this problem, one thing I thought off is to use reflection instead of directly using the dll references in project, not sure how to do with references like inheriting the sap classes in our custom class, could you please help.

```
 class RfcConfig : IDestinationConfiguration   // How to inherit IDestinationConfiguration using reflection and how to handle events using reflection
{
 private Dictionary<string, RfcConfigParameters> availableDestinations = new Dictionary<string, RfcConfigParameters>();
        public bool ChangeEventsSupported()
        {
            return true;
        }

        RfcDestinationManager.ConfigurationChangeHandler changeHandler;

        public event RfcDestinationManager.ConfigurationChangeHandler ConfigurationChanged
        {
            add { changeHandler += value; }
            remove { changeHandler -= value; }
        }
 private void AddOrEditDestination(RfcConfigParameters parameters)
        {
            string name = parameters[RfcConfigParameters.Name];
            if (availableDestinations.ContainsKey(name))
            {
                // Fire a change event
                if (changeHandler != null)
                {
                    RfcConfigurationEventArgs eventArgs = new RfcConfigurationEventArgs(RfcConfigParameters.EventType.CHANGED, parameters);
                    changeHandler(name, eventArgs);
                }
            }

            // Replace the current parameters of an existing destination or add a new one
            availableDestinations[name] = parameters;
        }
public RfcConfigParameters GetParameters(string destinationName)
        {
            RfcConfigParameters foundDestination;
            availableDestinations.TryGetValue(destinationName, out foundDestination);
            return foundDestination;

        }
  public string Disconnect( string name = null)
        {
            try
            {
                if (name == null)
                {
                    changeHandler(name, new RfcConfigurationEventArgs(RfcConfigParameters.EventType.DELETED));
                }
                foreach (var availableDestination in availableDestinations)
                {
                    changeHandler(availableDestination.Key, new RfcConfigurationEventArgs(RfcConfigParameters.EventType.DELETED));
                }

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                var exMsg = $"Error while closing the connection for SAP adapter : [{name}] \n Error : {ex.Message}";
                return exMsg;
            }
            return $"Connection for SAP adapter: {name} closed.";
        }

private void AddOrEditDestination(RfcConfigParameters parameters)
        {
            string name = parameters[RfcConfigParameters.Name];
            if (availableDestinations.ContainsKey(name))
            {
                // Fire a change event
                if (changeHandler != null)
                {
                    RfcConfigurationEventArgs eventArgs = new RfcConfigurationEventArgs(RfcConfigParameters.EventType.CHANGED, parameters);
                    changeHandler(name, eventArgs);
                }
            }

            // Replace the current parameters of an existing destination or add a new one
            availableDestinations[name] = parameters;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using reflection, since it will be a huge pain. I would instead suggest catching the resolution exception, and provide some fallback if the dlls does not exist. .net should resolve dlls as needed, in practice this should mean the dll is loaded the first time a method using any type from the dll is called.

To solve this I would suggest creating an interface for the methods provided by SAP

```
public interface IMySAPInterface{
    //...
}
```

and a implementation that uses the actual SAP types. To enforce this it would be recommended to place this in a different project, and this project would be the only one allowed to reference the SAP dlls.

```
internal class MySAPInterface{
    private SomeTypeDefinedInTheNonredistributableDll myType;
    //...
}
```

In the same project you would have a factory method that tries to create the class. This should be the only public method in the project:

```
public static IMySAPInterface TryCreateSAP(){
    try{
         return new MySAPInterface(); // This needs to ensure the relevant dlls are actually loaded
     }
     catch(FileLoadException){ // might also be other exceptions, like BadImageFormatException
          return null; // some way to handle load failures
     }
  }
```

The code that uses the `IMySAPInterface` would need to initialize it once, and check it for null each time it is used. You could also provide an Null-implementation of the interface that does whatever you want to do if the dlls are missing.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I haven't tried but on a high level how that would solve the problem, if we are making a new project which will reference SAP libraries then I guess it will give same error right ??

Comment: We have post build event script while compiling the windows service application like   
 -> xcopy "$(ProjectDir)..\NewClassDLL.dll" "$(ProjectDir)Plugins" /S /C /D /F /Y

-> xcopy "$(ProjectDir)..\OLDClassDLL.dll" "$(ProjectDir)Plugins" /S /C /D /F /Y                          The script basically copies all the dlls in PLUGIN folder and then DirectoryCatalog(MefFunctions.GetPlugInDir())  loads all assemblies from plugin folder so over here if the sap dlls are missing then it will throw error.

Comment: @Mysterious288 The point is to make a wrapper around the SAP dlls that handle loading failures. All other projects must use the wrapper and not the SAP dlls directly.

Comment: Sorry I 'm still confused whether the wrapper/new project should reference sap dll or not because if we reference it then it will throw error and not sure how to handle that error, do you think it will work in my case,if you provide a little detailed information that will help me to understand, thanks for helping so far.

Comment: Will Embedded resource logical solution to my problem ??

Comment: @Mysterious288 First of all you need to consider how the application should work if you do not have access to the dlls. Show an error message? Disable some functionality? Even if you can catch the exceptions you must know what to do in that case.